# SugarCRM - How to create entry using Module Class

Tags: class, backend, sugarcrm

Here's what I'm trying to do, for example Cases Module, after creating an entry in Accounts I want it to automatically, for example, creates a Contacts entry. I want to use a Logic Hooks and I already know how to do that.

What I don't know yet is how to create a new entry using the Contacts class, how do I do this? with of course a relationship with Contacts and Cases, or is there any other way to do this? So its like making an entry through the backend.

Regards,
Ronel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code as a logic hook function of Cases

```
<?php
...
// Logic hook (beforeSave or afterSave) function of cases
function logicHookFunction ($bean, $event, $arguments) {
  // create new contact
  $contact = new Contact();
  $contact->last_name = 'something';
  $contact->email1 = 'something@example.com';
  $contact->save();

  // add relationship to case ($bean)
  $bean->load_relationship('contacts');
  $bean->contacts->add($contact->id,array());
}

...
?>
```

Comment: so, all I need to fill in are the mandatory fields? the Contacts id is available after save(), am I correct?

Comment: yes, enter the mandatory fields and the Contacts id will be generated by SugarCRM when save() is called.